# MapStruct and parametrized constructor?

Tags: mapping, instantiation, mapstruct

Is there support in MapStruct for parametrized constructors?

I found in many posts from 2015 that this feature will be implemented in `1.1` release. Now I'm using `1.1.0.Final` but I'm not able to find out in doc how to map target object that requires parametrized constructor.

**Is this feature implemented?**

Answer (score 3):

Support for parametrized constructors is available since version 1.4 as described in chapter ["Object Factories"](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for other constructors than parameterless (default) constructors currently. There is [issue #73](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/73) for tracking it. It's high on our wish list and I hope it will be done soon, but it's too early to tell when it will be.

Comment: Thanks, and what's workaround? Use Builder pattern, or?

Comment: You could write your own [custom method](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods) for those object.